# Yuidoc-style comments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, documentation, yuidoc

How can I use YUIDoc comments in Ruby? The best I can come up with is this:

```
  ##*
  # Get Query history
  # @type {Array} Past search query objects
  # @param {int} limit The number of objects to return. Defaults to 10. (Max 100).
  # @param {boolean} only_visible limit the search to visible items. Defaults to true.
  #
```

And this:

```
  #/**
  # * Get Query history
  # * @type {Array} Past search query objects
  # * @param {int} limit The number of objects to return. Defaults to 10. (Max 100).
  # * @param {boolean} only_visible limit the search to visible items. Defaults to true.
  # */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed YUIDoc comments inside a Ruby multiline comment, like this:

```
=begin
/**
* Get Query history
* @type {Array} Past search query objects
* @param {int} limit The number of objects to return. Defaults to 10. (Max 100).
* @param {boolean} only_visible limit the search to visible items. Defaults to true.
*/
=end
```

The `=` character before `begin` and `end` *must be* on the first column of the line.

Comment: Interesting. Is that considered OK style? Please let me state that I am a javascript developer with very little rails experience. It almost looks like a CDATA block or something. By the way.. what does the =begin and =end actually do??

Comment: @AlexKessaris `=begin` and `=end` are delimiters for multiline comments, similar to `/*` and `*/` in JavaScript. They are quite uncommon in Ruby code but in this case they are the only choice.

Comment: Cool! Thank you for your help in this matter. Incidentally, I would be interested to know more options on commenting in Ruby. I'll look it up online, but your thoughts are also very welcome!

Comment: In the end I guess the outcome of this question has been to adopt YARD-style comments. Thank you very much for your help @toro2k